# Curl php выполнить запрос

Tags: php

В терминале получаю корректно, как так же выполнить используя php ?

```
curl -i -X GET https://api.delivery.yandex.ru/orders/7988141/statuses -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: OAuth AgAAAAAHB88WAAbM49Vp7tPRvU59kdACMaxs342'
```

Comment: А где код для выполнения этого запроса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$curl = curl_init();
$options = [
                CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.delivery.yandex.ru/orders/7988141/statuses',
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [ 
                    "Authorization: OAuth AgAAAAAHB88WAAbM49Vp7tPRvU59kdACMaxs342",
                    "Content-Type: application/json"
                ],
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET"
];

curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
$responce = curl_exec($curl);
$errors = curl_error($curl);

if(!$errors){
 echo json_decode($responce);
}
curl_close($curl);
```